# get_terms Parent Tags

Tags: terms

I'm using a function that I think it uses this code to get the tags from a taxonomy:

```
if($taxonomy){ $tags = get_terms( $taxonomy, 'order=ASC&hide_empty='.$show_empty.'');
```

As it is, is extracts all the tags(parent & child) from that taxonomy. But what I need is to extract only the parent or child tags from a specific `tag_ID(14)`.

I've tried to include `child_of=14` and `parent=0` but couldn't make it. Could you give a advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "only the parent or child tags"? Aren't the two mutually exclusive?

Comment: yes, or one or another. Tried both ways and cannot make it work. What I would prefer is to get only top parent tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parent` argument should do what you are asking.

> > **parent**
> >         (integer) Get direct children of this term (only terms whose explicit parent is this value). If 0 is passed, only top-level terms
> >     are returned. Default is an empty string.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

That is `parent=14` should get all of the immediate children of term 14, but no grandchildren or great-grandchildren. If that is not working I have to assume that a plugin or something in your theme is interfering, or I have completely misunderstood your problem.